# MailCore2 iOS - Getting all "Received" extra headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, imap, mailcore2

I have a problem to get ALL `"Received"` extra headers form an `MCOMessageHeader` obj in a MailCore2 iOS Lib. In `ConnectionLogger` I see all of 4 received fields, but how can get all 4 entries?

If I use `mHeader.extraHeaderValue(forName: "Received") -> String` , I get only one, I don't see any method definitions in `MCOMessageHeader` something like `mHeader.extraHeaderValues(forName: "Received") -> [String]`

What I tried:

```
setup fetchOperation

... `
    let requestKind:MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind = [.headers, .extraHeaders, .fullHeaders]
    let fetchOperation:MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation = imapSession.fetchMessagesOperation(withFolder: folder, requestKind: requestKind, uids: uids)
    fetchOperation.extraHeaders = ["Received", "DKIM-Signature"]
    ...

Get extra headers:

...
let message:MCOIMAPMessage  = ...
//I get here only first received
let receivedExtraField = mHeader.extraHeaderValue(forName: "Received") as String
...
ConnectionLogger: all user data where replaced with "some_string"


* 10 FETCH (UID 16 ENVELOPE ("Fri, 16 Jun 2017 13:12:26 +0200 (CEST)" "=?UTF-8?Q?some_string!?=" ((NIL NIL "noreply" "some_string")) (("some_string" NIL "noreply" "some_string")) ((NIL NIL "noreply" "some_string")) ((NIL NIL "some_string" "gmail.com")) NIL NIL NIL "<some_string>") BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE SUBJECT FROM SENDER REPLY-TO TO CC MESSAGE-ID REFERENCES IN-REPLY-TO REFERENCES RECEIVED DKIM-SIGNATURE)] {1161}

Received: by some_string with SMTP id f46csp1131634qge;

        Fri, 16 Jun 2017 04:12:27 -0700 (PDT)

Received: from some_string (some_string. [IP])

        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id z19si2877034wmz.6.2017.06.16.04.12.26

        for <some_string>

        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);

        Fri, 16 Jun 2017 04:12:27 -0700 (PDT)

Received: from some_string (some_string[IP])

    by some_string (Postfix) with ESMTP id C5CCD61DED

    for <some_string>; Fri, 16 Jun 2017 13:12:26 +0200 (CEST)

Received: from some_string (localhost [IP])

    by some_string (Postfix) with ESMTP id C327B4043B

    for <some_string>; Fri, 16 Jun 2017 13:12:26 +0200 (CEST)

Date: Fri, 16 Jun 2017 13:12:26 +0200 (CEST)

Sender: some_string <some_string>

To: some_string

Message-ID: <some_string>

Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?some_string!?=

From: some_string


)
7 OK UID FETCH completed
```

`

What am I doing wrong? Does somebody has any idea?